# Work around to use state value in a server component

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js13

I have the following component which works fine as is.
Is located at `my-app/src/app/page.js`.

Using `NextJS` version `13.4.13`.

But I don't want to hard code the country code value.

I want it to come from a state value.

State value gets set based on a drop down component selection.

I am using `zustand`.

I can't just do the following and use it in my component below as it is a server component.

```
import useStore from "@/utils/store"; // zustand store setup which works fine
// this will throw errors, trying to use state in a server component
// this is valid if I had used it in a client component.
const countryCode = useStore((state) => state.countryCode);
```

If I switch it to a client component then, I can't use `async` for the component anymore.

It just messes up current approach.

Is there a standard practice here.

What would be the right approach to be able to use the state value in following component?

Or a way to break it out somehow so that state usage doesn't occur in this component.

```
const getData = async (locale) => {
  const res = await fetch(`localhost:3001/api/${locale}`)
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error('Failed to fetch data')
  }
  return await res.json();
};

const Home = async () => {
  // can't do this in a server component
  // const countryCode = useStore((state) => state.countryCode);

  // I don't want to hardcode AU. Use the countryCode state value instead.
  const data = await getData('AU'); 
  return (
    <main className='margin'>
      <MyComponent data={data} />
    </main>
  );
};

export default Home;
```